# How to position logo on web header independently of menu tabs while still having them in the same row?

Tags: html, css

So, here I have a logo and I can't seem to find a way to position the logo AND the headers' tabs so it vertically aligns the row. This is because the logo is taller than the tabs (text) and I can't find another way to vertically align the tabs other than using padding to manually make it appear vertically aligned to the center. To achieve the 'same row' effect, I put the logo (png image) in an li tag along with the other tabs in the same ul tag. However, I can't add different padding to the logo and the tabs because they are grouped in the same ul tag, and if I separate it it will not be in the same row. So, either the image is vertically aligned to the center and the tabs are not, or the tabs are vertically aligned to the center and the logo is not because I give it a fixed padding. I don't know how to make it automatically vertically align to the div either, and options on this website just messes up the website for some reason.

So here is the sample image:

[image]

And, here is what the header looks like (screenshot):

[image]

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/5em0r7mm/) is the code of my header (simplified so doesn't look exactly like screenshot):

```
<style>
/*LOGO FORMATTING:*/
#icon {
  text-align: left;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
}

#header/*MENU CSS*/ {
  background: red;  /*To demonstrate what part of the header this commands:*/
  border: 0.5px solid #E3E3E3;
  height: 50px; /*Height of Header*/

}

.wrap { 
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%; /*Width of Entire Page*/
  max-width: 1000px; /*Width of Entire Page*/
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.columns {
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 40px;
  height:00%;
  float: right;
}
#nav {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#nav li a, #nav li {float: left;}
#nav li {list-style: none;position: relative;}
#nav li a {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5E5E5E;
  background: white;
}
#nav li a{ 
  transition: linear 100ms;
}
#nav li a:hover {color: black;}
.hasChildren {position: absolute;}
#nav li ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 101%;
  padding: 0; margin: 0;
}
#nav li:hover > ul {z-index: 289; display: block;}
#nav li ul { 
  width: 120px;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px lightgrey;
}
#nav a{
  color: black; 
  text-decoration: none; /* remove link underline*/
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Archivo Narrow', sans-serif;
}

/*Width of entire header*/
ul.columns {width: 1000px;}

/*Search input formatting*/
.search-input {
  width: 150px;
  height: 24px;
  padding: 0 7px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background: white;
  -webkit-transition: width 400ms;
  -moz-transition: width 400ms;
  -o-transition: width 400ms;
  transition: width 400ms;
}
.search-input:hover {
  outline: none;
  opacity:0.99;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) inset; 
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: width 300ms;
  -moz-transition: width 300ms;
  -o-transition: width 300ms;
  transition: width 300ms;
}
.search-input:focus {
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: width 300ms;
  -moz-transition: width 300ms;
  -o-transition: width 300ms;
  transition: width 300ms;
}
input:focus {outline: none;}
#search-icon {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  height: 15px;
}

</style>

<div class="wrap" id="header">   

<ul class="columns" id="nav">
    <li><a href="#"><img id="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JLVA.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Art</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Literature</a></li>
    <li> 
      <form  method="post" action="#"  id="searchform"> 
        <img id="search-icon" src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/132068/isolated/preview/f9bb81e576c1a361c61a8c08945b2c48-search-icon-by-vexels.png">
        <input  class="search-input" type="text" name="search-input" placeholder="Search..." /> 
        <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Go" id="search-btn" /> 
      </form> 

    </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

The red makes it obvious that there is a strange white space all around the entire image that I can't seem to get rid of AND I can't find a way to position it so it vertically aligns. All feedback is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The image https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JLVA.png is not tightly cropped around the logo. It has a white background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to anchor (a) tag that has image like this:

```
<a href="#" class="logo"><img id="icon" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JLVA.png"></a>
```

Then change your CSS to not add padding to this anchor tag...

```
#nav li a:not(.logo) {
        padding: 15px 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #5E5E5E;
        background: white;
    }
```

[Here is the updated Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/g5Lrxe9L/10/)